# How to display text merging two languages (english+arabic)

Tags: html, character-encoding, arabic

From last 15 days or more am struggling with an strange issue.
Actually i have some text in Arabic language but in between some English text too.

```
MY NAME "some arabic text"
"some arabic text"
"some arabic text" english "some arabic text"
```

problem: I am unable to copy paste it as it is since eng is left to right and arabic is right to left.

so how to copy paste this text in html file.

do i need set some attribute in html?

Comment: @HashimR : Can you please help me on it

Comment: Do you need to copy paste it manually? Is the original text in the correct format?

Answer (score 2):

Just enclose the Arabic in a `<span>` tag, with a class that has the direction CSS property set to ltr.

```
MY NAME <span class="artext">"some arabic text"</span>
<span class="artext">"some arabic text"</span>
<span class="artext">"some arabic text"</span> english <span class="artext">"some arabic text"</span>
```

and

```
.artext {
    direction: rtl;
 }
```

somewhere in the style definition file or in the head section.

Comment: No :( say i have "arabictext Play™" than its cuming in mail as "™ arabictext Play"

Comment: How to do this in java: json rendering?